# ConfusionMatrix prediction/actual

Tags: r, r-caret

I tried to predict diabetes "yes" or "no". I trained my data set as you may see below. afterwards I predicted the values. Then I created a vector  and tried to use confusion matrix in order to check sens, spec and accuracy. But I always get an error.

```
df_fold <- train(data = df_train, Outcome~., method = "glmnet",
             family = "binomial",
             metric = "ROC",
             preProcess = c("zv", "center", "scale"),
               trControl = trainControl(
                 method = "cv", number = 10,
                 summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                 classProbs = TRUE,
                 verboseIter = TRUE
             ))


p <- predict.train(df_fold, df_test, type = "prob")

y_or_no <- ifelse(p > 0.8, "yes", "no")
p_yes <- factor(y_or_no, levels = levels(df_test$Outcome))

confusionMatrix.train(p_yes, df_test$Outcome, dnn = c("prediction", "actual"))
```

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: What does `df_test` look like?

Comment: I figured  out that the p_yes hast 477 values. That's too much because of the predict function. It gives me a df with 243 obs. of two variables instead of 243 obs of 1 variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are after `confusionMatrix` not `confusionMatrix.train`

```
confusionMatrix(p_yes, df_test$Outcome, dnn = c("prediction", "actual"))
```

---

Based on caret documentation, `confusionMatrix.train` is for

> Using a train, rfe, sbf object, determine a confusion matrix based on
> the resampling procedure

```
confusionMatrix.train(fitted_model)
```

Comment: If want to compare actual and predicted values. In your first version there's no comparison.

Comment: Yes, you should not have used (`confusionMatrix.train`) that one. Use the other.

Comment: If I use your second version that's also not goint to work because my p has 243 observations of two variables. outcome is just one variable. so they can't be compared.

Comment: I used just confusionMatrix before and it worked but I need to use

('''reg_model <- glm(data = df_train, Outcome ~ . , family = "binomial")''')
('''p <- predict(reg_model, df_test, type = "response")''')

but then I haven't used my cross validation glmnet.

Comment: The two variables are prob and 1-prob. So use the one appropriate column. (note that the row sums add to 1.) Hope you can see the importance of provinding a reproducible example.